# Grunt - Live reload not working with grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to get Grunt to reload my js files when I change them using `grunt-contrib-watch`.  Here is my `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({

     connect: {
      all: {
        options:{
          port: 9000,
          hostname: "0.0.0.0",
          base: 'app',
          keepalive: true,
          middleware: function(connect, options) {

            return [

              require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet,

              connect.static(options.base)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      all: {
        path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.all.options.port%>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      js: {
        files: ['app/js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint'],
      }
    }
  });

  // Creates the `server` task
  grunt.registerTask('server',[
    'open',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect',
    'watch'
  ]);
};
```

When I change a js file nothing happens.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have a Livereload plugin for your browser?

Comment: I am using Chrome and I do have the Livereload plugin.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with my `base` in my connect configuration?  I also added to my `index.html` to my watch configuration and it isnt finding it either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tried using the `livereloadSnippet` in the middleware before, so I'm not sure what might be wrong there. But if you just want a regular LiveReload setup you can just make use of the `livereload` option provided by the `grunt-contrib-connect` plugin:

```
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    all: {
      options:{
        port: 9000,
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        base: 'app',
        keepalive: true,
        livereload: true,
        open: true
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    js: {
      files: ['app/js/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('server',[
  'connect',
  'watch'
]);
```

Comment: You can just simply add open: true inside connect:all task's option object and get the same result.

Comment: Look after the folder structure as code above going to app folder. TO go to top directory of repo change base to base:'.' . Cheers